# Limitations of queries in CommandText property for EntityDataSource

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, entity-framework, compatibility, entitydatasource

I'm using `EntityDataSource` control in my ASP.NET application developed under Visual Studio 2012. It has a `CommandText` property which one can use to select the data for the control. While it is set as an SQL query, I often have the situation when a query executes well under SSMS, but fails for `EntityDataSource`. Here is the short list of limitations encountered this week:

- Cannot use `SELECT *`, need to specify fields explicitly
- Obligatory aliases for nested queries
- Cannot use some system functions, like `isnull`

Bottom line, I have two questions:

1. How to get the full list of such limitations?
2. What to use instead of the `isnull` function?

Comment: I've looked around. Entity Framework uses EntitySql which is rather limited. To replace isnull [use case .. when .. then](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399229.aspx) construct. Unfortunately I couldn't find a feature table that would list differences between the two and workarounds.

Comment: You comment should be an answer :) And I found this MSDN article named "How Entity SQL Differs from Transact-SQL": http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738573.aspx. I think, I'll find something useful in it.

Comment: Great. Obviously I didn't look hard enough :-) This will certainly come-in handy for me some day.